# Can I save plugin from Eclipse Market to flashdrive and install to somewhere without internet connection?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

This is plugin that I want,

Eclipse Color Theme 0.9.1
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme
https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme

I only use internet at work,
Is it possible to save this plugin and make a local install at my home ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse Marketplace page for [Eclipse Color Theme 0.9.1](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) does not have a download link.

The safest thing to do would be to set up your work Eclipse however you want, zip your work Eclipse, and unzip your work Eclipse onto your computer at home.

You could try and pick out the pieces of the Eclipse Color Theme 0.9.1 plug-in from the Eclipse plugins and features directories, but if you miss something, the plug-in won't work on your home Eclipse.